# Contradicting if else statements

Tags: r, if-statement

I have created a dataset with the current run differentials by team for the 2019-2020 MLB season. I am trying to predict the outcome (if you should place a bet, and which team you should bet on). It is a very basic function but I am having trouble with else if statements contradicting themselves.

Notice in the code below that the statement:

```
if(x > y)
```

contradicts with:

```
if(x > 2*y)
```

When I call the function with x more than double y, it still returns "BETX" rather than the desired "LOCKX"

I am going to try to do the same thing for "LOCKY", but I would love to sort out this issue first.

Thank you in advance!

```
 bets <- function(x, y){
  if(x > y){
    return("BETX")
  } 
  else if(x == y){
    return("NO BET")
  }
  else if(x > 2*y){
    return("LOCKX")
  }else{
    return("BETY")
  }

}
bets(cubsdiff, diamondbacksdiff) ## BET CUBS
bets(yankeesdiff, royalsdiff) ## BET YANKS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could approach this problem.

ask if `x > 2*y` first

```
if(x > 2*y){
    return("LOCKX")
}
else if(x > y){
    return("BETX")
}
...
```

ask if `x > 2*y` inside the `x>y` block

```
if(x > y){
    if(x > 2*y){
        return("LOCKX")
    } else {
        return("BETX")
    }
}
...
```

or replace your `x > y` statement with a compound statement

```
if (x > y & x <= 2*y){
    return("BETX")
} 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if say x = 50 and y = 5 then you have x > y  and x > 2*y 
so there is no contradiction.

But you could add the following to your first `if` condition:

```
if (x > y & x <= 2*y){
    return("BETX")
  }
```

So you only return BETX if x is larger than y but not too large (i.e. smaller than 2*y).

Otherwise you could first check if x > 2y and afterwards check if x > y.

```
 bets <- function(x, y){
  if(x > 2y){
    return("LOCKX")
  } 
  else if(x == y){
    return("NO BET")
  }
  else if(x > y){
    return("BETX")
  }else{
    return("BETY")
  }

}
```